# "Error: bind EAFNOSUPPORT" when trying to use udp6

Tags: node.js, linux-kernel, udp, ipv6

I have a script running smoothly on one server

```
// create a new UDP server
dgram = require('dgram'); 
server = dgram.createSocket('udp6');

server.bind(20500,config.server.ip);
```

on the second server executing the code throws an error: "Error: bind EAFNOSUPPORT"

node version is `v0.10.26` on both machines, however the one where it is working is `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-56-virtual x86_64)` and the one where it is not working is `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-312-ec2 x86_64)`

so the Kernel versions are quite different. What could possible be a fix to for this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing to

```
server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
```

and setting my server ip to 0.0.0.0

I was not able to make `udp6` work